# HTML5 CANVAS draw image

Tags: image, html, draw

Here is my question

I kind of not understand what is the sx and sy is for in below function

context.drawImage(Image, sx, sy, sw, sh, dx, dy, dw, dh);

what I really mean is if we change the values of sx and sy and set our dx and dy to a fix value, let say dx=0 and dy=0, is there really going to make any different to our image on the canvas when we set sx=300 and sy=300 as compared to sx=0 and sy=0? I mean the destination image is still in the location dx=dy=0 even we set sx and sy to different values, right? I know this is a stupid question but I just need to know the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 17):

(sx, sy) is the top-left corner of the source rectangle (**within** the source image) which are going to draw to the destination. Take a look at the diagram below:

[image]

[[Reference]](http://diveintohtml5.info/canvas.html)

sx=0,sy=0 is different from sx=300,sy=300 because they refer to different source rectangles.

Comment: what will be the effect of different source rectangles on the image? will the position of the image on the canvas change?

Comment: If you have different source rectangles you will be drawing different parts of the source image. If you wish to draw the entire source image then you will have to start from 0,0.

Comment: yes but why do we need to place sx and sy at different location, aren't we get the same image at the fix dx=0 and dy=0 location? i mean the destination image will still be the same although sx and sy has changed, right?

Comment: In some cases, you may not want to draw the entire source image. Say you only want to draw the lower half of it, then you will have to shift sx and sy.

Comment: ah ha, now thing has started to get clearer, please show me an example, I will answer you back a question in the future to show my thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function init_sketch() {
img.src = 'http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/3/3yiC6Yq.jpg';
context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}
```